# How to achieve the Semantic UI Site's sticky menu

Tags: javascript, css, semantic-ui

I am trying to sort out how the Semantic-UI site made their sticky side-menu.

- http://semantic-ui.com/elements/button.html
- http://learnsemantic.com/developing/customizing.html#introduction

The sticky menu that scrolls with you.

[image]

It is inside of a `left rail` or a `right rail`, and unlike the examples in their [rail documents](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/rail.html) or [sticky documents](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sticky.html) it resizes to fit the size of the viewport instead of pushing outside of the viewport or into the container as you change the width of the page.

Here is an example JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bpoguom4/3/show/

**Run Snippet Full screen and resize your window to see what I mean.**

```js
$('.ui.sticky').sticky({
  context: $('.ui.container')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui text container segment">

<div class="ui left rail">
  <div class="ui sticky">
    <div class="ui segment">
      <div class="ui title">
       Some Stuff Goes Here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
    <br>content<br>
</div>
```

I cannot figure out how they achieve this with Semantic UI. Is this not part of the framework itself? If not, how would I achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to include the sticky.min.css from the semantic/components folder.

Comment: Best to give an example. For more info see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This should probably be a comment, I'm using the entirety of the semantic CSS & JS package.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I'm just now finding my way around.